# Convergence of $\int_0^\infty x \sin e^x \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to demonstrate the convergence/divergence of a couple of integrals. They are:

1. $\int_0^\infty x \sin e^x\,dx$
2. $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(\sec x)\,dx$

There was a previous exercise similar to the first one, $\int_0^\infty e^x \sin e^x \, dx$. I concluded that this one diverges, since by substitution I was able to change it to $\int_1^\infty \sin u\ du$. But I haven't been as successful in substitution for the first one: if we try $u=e^x$, we get $x \sin e^x \, dx = \ln(u)\ e^{-u}\sin u \,du$, but now we can't make the limits work.

For the second one, obviously the problem is that $\sec$ goes to infinity as $x\to \pi/2$, so $\sin$ oscillates wildly. How can we investigate the convergence here?

Comment: I was investigating $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^{n}x \sin{e^x}dx$

Comment: @CameronWilliams What do you mean? It's an improper integral. That is the only way to make sense of Riemann integrals on an infinite interval. Or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first function, we are integrating from $0$ to $M$, and then making $M$ get big.

Rewrite our function as $xe^{-x} e^x\sin(e^x)$. Integrate by parts, letting $u=xe^{-x}$ and $dv=e^x \sin(e^x)\,dx$.

Then $du=(-xe^{-x}+e^{-x})\,dx$ and we can take $v$ to be $-\cos(e^x)$. Now everything behaves very nicely for large $M$ because of the killer $e^{-x}$, and we get convergence.

Comment: Thanks! That's a clever trick. That completely answers the first question.

Comment: You are welcome. It isn't really a *trick*, it's a *method*. Integration by parts can be awfully useful for gaining control over the size of things.

Comment: By "trick" I meant the insertion of the $e^{-x}$, $e^{x}$ terms. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to see why the second one converges.  Here's a couple:  You can write it as an alternating series, and use the [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).  Alternatively, since $\sec(x)$ is monotonic on $[0,\pi/2]$, you can let $u=\sec(x)$, and rewrite the integral as $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\sec(x))dx=\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}du,$$ which is convergent.