# Convergence of $\int_{1}^{\infty}x\cdot \sin{(e^x})\,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This question was already asked here: [Convergence of $\int_0^\infty x \sin e^x \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434122/convergence-of-int-0-infty-x-sin-ex-dx)
. Unfortunately due to my low rank I am unable to ask questions in it. I am wondering how does this integral converge from $\int_{1}^{\infty}$? It seems like it blows up past 1 as $x\to\infty$. Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: It blows up and blows down and there is a lot of cancellation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{M}x\sin(e^x)\,dx = \int_{1}^{e^M}\frac{\log z}{z}\sin(z)\,dz $$
and the last integral is conditionally convergent by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test), since $\sin(z)$ has a bounded primitive while $\frac{\log z}{z}$ is decreasing and converging to zero on $(e,+\infty)$. It is interesting to notice that:

> $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,\log(x)\,dx = -\frac{\gamma \pi}{2} \tag{1}$$

holds by differentiation under the integral sign, since:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(x)\,x^{\alpha-1}\,dx = \Gamma(a)\sin\left(\frac{\pi a}{2}\right)$$
holds as a consequence of $\mathcal{L}(\sin x)=\frac{1}{1+s^2}$ and $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(x^a)=\frac{1}{s^{\alpha+1}\Gamma(-\alpha)}.$
It follows that:

> $$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\log(x)\,dx &=& -\frac{\gamma \pi}{2}-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\,\log(x)\,dx\\&=&\color{red}{-\frac{\gamma \pi}{2}+\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2(2n+1)!}}.\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*} $$

Comment: Thank you so much. My friend and I had initially done the change of variable getting log(u), but we messed up with it. We were trying to use Dirichlet's test but came up short. This helps out a lot.